# angular js remove duplicate key field from all arrays inside an array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```js
app.filter('unique', function() {
   return function(collection, keyname) {
      var output = [], 
          keys = [];

      angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
          var key = item[keyname];
          if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
              keys.push(key);
              output.push(item);
          }
      });

      return output;
   };
});


/* mainOptions = [ a1[],b2[],c3[]]
  subOptions a1[] = [fuzzyoptions{ optionid : 11},fuzzyoptions{ optionid : 13},fuzzyoptions{ optionid : 11},fuzzyoptions{ optionid : 12}]
 subOptions b1[] = [fuzzyoptions{ optionid : 12},fuzzyoptions{ optionid : 13},fuzzyoptions{ optionid : 11},fuzzyoptions{ optionid : 12}] 
  subOptions b1[] = [fuzzyoptions{ optionid : 19},fuzzyoptions{ optionid : 23},fuzzyoptions{ optionid : 11},fuzzyoptions{ optionid : 12}] */

/* I want ng-repeat to remove duplicates for optionid in all arrays inside one main array */

/*so check will go for fuzzyoptions{ optionid : 11},fuzzyoptions{ optionid : 13},fuzzyoptions{ optionid : 12},fuzzyoptions{ optionid : 19},fuzzyoptions{ optionid : 23} only 5 times*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-repeat = "main in mainOptions">
  <div ng-repeat = "sub in main.SubOptions  | unique: 'sub.fuzzyoptions.optionid'">
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want to remove duplicate optionids field;s values from  all   subOption arrays inside mainOptions arrays.
I want to achieve removing duplicate key-value fields for all arrays inside one parent array using custom filter or track by or any other solution using angular js

Answer (score 0):

I made a [small fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0hoge5z/) that can be improved to attend your needs. It's a filter that receives a key and a list, returning the list with the unique values of that key.

```
.filter('unique', function() {
    return function(collection, keyname) {
        var output = {};

        for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
            output[collection[i][keyname]] = collection[i];
        }

        output = Object.keys(output).map(function (key) {return output[key]});

        return output;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your html like (ng-repeat="record in records|removeDuplicate") it will work

```
 .filter('removeDuplicate', function() {
   return function(array) {
   var array1 = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      for(var key1 in array[i]){
        var notfind=true;
        if(array1 && (array1.length==0)){
         array1.push(array[i]);
          }
        for(var j=0;j<array1.length;j++){
          for(var key in array1[j]){
             if(array1[j][key]==array[i][key1]){
                notfind=false;
               }}}
            if(notfind){
               array1.push(array[i])
                    }}}
                  return array1;
                 };
                       });
```